# In vue, how do I filter a data object to only show values from the last 24 hours?

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I have an array with some data objects that were created on various dates. I would like to only display the objects that were created within the last 24 hours.

I have tried to use moment for this, by using subtract on the date values, but it has no effect. Maybe someone here could come up with a suggestion.

Here are my computed properties. I use these because I am outputting the data in a bootstrap table, so the "key" represents the different values inside the object.

My table:

```html
<b-card class="mt-4 mb-4">
  <b-table
    :items="tasks"
    :fields="fields"
    sort-desc
  />
</b-card>
```

My array (I am actually importing from a database, but for this question I will just write it manually) Please note I am just showing a single object here. In reality I have hundreds of objects

```
   data: {
    tasks: [
      { message: 'Foo' },
      { creationDateTime: '03-02-2022' },
      { isRead: false }
    ]
   }
```

In my computed properties I then pass them to the table

```
    computed: {
      fields() {
        return [
            key: 'message',
            label: 'message'),
            sortable: true,
          },
          {
            key: 'creationDateTime',
            label: 'Date created',
            formatter: date => moment(date).subtract(24, 'hours').locale(this.$i18n.locale).format('L'),
            sortable: true,
          },
          {
            key: 'isRead',
            label: 'Has been read'),
            sortable: true,
          }
        ]
      },
    },
```

As I said, using subtract does not work. It still shows all objects in my database

I tried doing the reduction on the whole array as well, but I just get the error:

> **"TypeError: this.list.filter is not a function"**

```
newTasks(){
  if(this.tasks){
    return moment(this.tasks.filter(task => !task.done)).subtract(24, 'hours')
  }
}
```

I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In Moment, you can check if a date is within the last 24 hours with:

```
moment().diff(yourDate, 'hours') < 24
```

(note that future dates will also pass this check, but you can easily adjust it).

You can put this into your computed property:

```
newTasks(){
  if(!this.tasks){
    return []
  }
  return this.tasks.filter(task => !task.done && moment().diff(task.creationDateTime, 'hours') < 24)
}
```

And that's it, now `newTasks` should contain all tasks from the last 24 hours that are not done.